# Gradle Sync: Wait for the other thread to finish acquiring the distribution never ends

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Created new Android Studio project. But Gradle Sync never ends:

> Gradle Sync: Wait for the other thread to finish acquiring the
>   distribution

I have checked Android Studio does not download data:

[image]

[image]

I have checked internet connection, it is working but it is slow.

[image]

Is this because of a slow internet connection? If no, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also met this problem.
Then I found out that this is due to the gradle of the project dependency is not downloaded.

**Ways to verify the problem:**

Check if there is a gradle file in the directory.

Linux:`~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

Windows:`C:\users\{user name}\.gradle\wrapper\dists`

If the file does not exist in the directory, Then this is what led.

**Ways to resolve the problem:**

wo need to download the configuration file manually.

1. Download the file(gradle) form https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ according to the `distributionUrl` in the `gradle-wrapper.properties`, infact You can modify it according to your needs.

   For example, in my `gradle-wrapper.properties`,
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`.
   So I should download the file`gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`
2. move the file(gradle-5.1.1-all.zip) you downloaded to the deepest part of above directory.

   For example, in my pc, its final position is `C:\Users\ufan0\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-all\97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg`.

   note: There will be undownloaded files in `C:\Users\ufan0\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-all\97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg` when you check there first, you can delete them, then move the zip of gradle to there.
3. Now you can restart the Android Studio, then choose `File -> Sync Project With Gradle Files`.

When these are all done, The Android Studio should be able to work properly.

note: In order to avoid this type of situation the next time, you can choose to configure the `Setting -> Gradle -> Use local gradle distribution`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, simple closing all the android studio projects and exiting android studio and opening it again solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1- Download the file gradle form URL https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip or look url in the gradle-wrapper.properties.

2- Copy the file (gradle-5.4.1-all) you downloaded to the deepest part of directory C:\users{user name}.gradle\wrapper\dists .

3- restart the Android Studio and run (Sync Project With Gradle Files).